# In PHPUnit how should I test when return values are complex objects

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I have 3 classes.

```
class Box{

    public $item1;
    public $item2;

    public function __construct($item1,$item2){
        $this->item = $item1;
        $this->item2 = $item2;
    }

    public function getItem1(){
        return $this->item1;
    }

}

class Details{

    public $stuff
    public $item1;
    public $item2;
    public $item3;
    public function __construct($stuff){
       $this->stuff = $stuff
    }

    public function setItem1($item){
        $this->item1 = $item;
    }
    public function setItem2($item){
        $this->item2 = $item;
    }

}

class Crate{

    public $box;
    private $stuffString = "Stuff";

    public function __construct(Box $box){
        $this->box = $box;
    }

    public function getDetails(){
        $details = new Details($stuffString);
        $details->setItem1($box->item1);
        $details->setItem2("Detail");
        return $details;
    }
}
```

The `Crate->getDetails()` method returns a Details object with data from the Box object. I want to write tests for this method.

```
function test_get_details(){

    $box = Mockery::mock(Box::class);
    $box->shouldReceive('getItem1')->andReturn("BoxItem");

    $crate= new Crate($box);
    $details = $crate->getDetails();

    $this->assertInstanceOf(Details::class,$details);
}
```

I create a mock of the Box class and pass it to constructor of Crate. When I call `$crate->getDetails();` it should return a Details object with

- $item1 = "BoxItem"
- $item2 = "Detail"
- $item3 = null

I know I can test this by doing for each item `$this->assertEquals("BoxItem",$details->item1);` etc... but is that the best way to go about it? Is there some PHPUnit tool to build up the desired Detials result and compare it

For Example

`$this->assertEquals(MockDetailObject,$details)`

or do I have to do a series of asserts to make sure the result is what I expect.

Note*

I know for my example this isn't a huge deal, I built it up quick to explain what I mean. But in the code I'm working on I ran into the same type of problem except the Details Object is more complex than just 3 strings.

Comment: Your `Details` object cannot be tested in other way than checking its type - it doesn't do anything. You need some post conditions - either return value or side effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your classes above, to unit test this properly, you would have to use DI to inject `\Details::class` into either `getDetails()` or the __constructor. Then write tests for each method of each class, mocking any class dependencies/properties

```
class Create
{
    public function getDetails(\Details $details)
}
```

```
//test.php
$mockDetails = $this->createMock(\Details::class)
                           ->expects($this-once())
                           ->method('item1')
                           ->with('some_arg')
                           ->willReturn('xyz')

$mockBox = $this-createMock(\Box::class)
   ......

$crate = new Create($boxMock);
$result = $crate->item1($mockDetails);
$this-assertSame('xyz', $result);
```

If it feels like your mocking way to much for one method, then you should consider refactoring to make the code more testable.

As far as assertions for multiple items, in PHPUnit you can use a dataprovider to pass an array of values as individual tests to one test method. 
[PHPUnit Docs - Data Providers](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/8.5/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#data-providers)

You would also write separate unit tests for the \Details::class that asserted what is passed to \Details::setItem1($item) is actually set on the item1 property. Ie.

Testing \Details::class -

```
//test2

public function test() {
    $details = new Details('some stuff');
    $details->setItem1('expected');
    self::assertSame('expected', $details->item1); 
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why I would need to create a details class to call the getDetails method. What if I cant create the details method outside because it needs a parameter from the Crate object in its constructor. I'm going to try to update my example to reflect what I mean

Comment: As it stands now, `getDetails()` is somewhat un-testable in a unit test. Reason being is within `getDetails()` you are creating a new object and have no way to control its output from a testing perspective. If you were writing a functional test, then you could write a test for the code as is. But for the Unit test, one would write a test that mocks details to give a immutable result for a given condition, as \Details::class is not the SUT with respect to \Crate::getDetails()

Comment: You would also write separate unit tests for the \Details::class the asserted what is passed to `\Details::setItem1($item)` is actually set on the item1 property. Ie. 
```

public function test() {
$details = new Details('some stuff');
$details->setItem1('expected');
self::assertSame('expected', $details->item1);
}

```

Comment: I wrote a post about the differences in unit tests vs functional tests. This might clarify my answer a little bit more. [Unit tests and functional tests, huh? Whats the difference?](https://dev.to/jrushlow/unit-and-functional-tests-huh-whats-the-difference-5a2n)

Comment: I did some major refactors to the code and was able to get it to a state where I could write better unit tests. I probably should have posted most of the original code because it's hard to translate to my quick example. But i pulled the initialization of the Details object out like you suggested and that did the trick

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR:** create a factory and test this factory 100%.

**From what I understood, your `Crate` class is both an entity and a factory.** You could refactor `Crate::getDetails` by moving this creation responsibility to a factory.

This way you'll be able to unit test the creation logic only by using the "Given, When, Then" structure. Check out [this post about clean tests](https://thephp.website/en/issue/clean-tests-with-php-and-phpunit/) and navigate to the "Tests should be concise and meaningful".

Having this structure will help you telling what are the inputs and outputs.
For example:

**CrateDetailsFactoryTest.php**

```php
class CrateDetailFactoryTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testCreateCrateDetail(): void
    {
        // Given
        $crate = $this->givenThereIsACrate();
        $boxes = $this->givenThereAreTwoRedBoxes();

        // When
        $crateDetail = $this->crateDetailFactory->createCrateDetail(
            $crate,
            $boxes
        );

        // Then
        // (Unnecessary instanceof, if you have strict return types)
        self::assertInstanceOf(Detail::class, $crateDetail);

        self::assertCount(2, $crateDetail->getBoxes());
        self::assertEquals(
            'red',
            $crateDetail->getBoxes()->first()->getColor()
        );
    }
}
```

With this your creation logic is covered; From here you can simply inject your factory where you need, and during the unit test time you just mock it away:

**CrateService.php**

```php
class CrateServiceTest extends TestCase
{
    private $crateDetailFactory;

    private $crateService;

    public function setUp(): void
    {
        $this->crateDetailFactory = $this->prophesize(CrateDetailFactory::class);

        $this->crateService = new CrateService(
            $this->crateDetailFactory->reveal()
        );
    }

    public function testAMethodThatNeedsCrateDetails(): void
    {
        // Given
        $crate = $this->givenIHaveACrateWithTwoBoxesInIt();
        $boxes = $crate->getBoxes();

        // When
        $result = $this->crateService->AMethodThatNeedsCrateDetails();

        // Then
        $this->crateDetailFactory->createCrateDetail($crate, $boxes)
            ->shouldBeCalledOnce();
    }
}
```

I hope that was useful. Cheers! :)

Comment: I ended up doing some big refactors. Your link helped. But I think you are right about the original classes being an entity and a factory.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Sometimes feels like creating more classes is not necessary, but tests always guide us to the correct path :D